# Why Session Out is happening when any pop-up window appears on the page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, modalpopupextender

This is my web page :

[image]

I have the pop-up window on my web page
That pop up appears on the click of "choose" button present on the above page
,It Looks like this :

[image]

After the selecting the image, I come back to my web page
and after coming back from pop up window, if I clicked any where on the page
the session is throwing me out to session time out page

Is there any problem to session time out because of the pop up window?
Please reply with solution

I Would be very thankful for this.

Comment: Do you have any Javascript code handling timeout conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the internal issue from where I was getting that issue.
My question was not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could increase the value for 'timeout' or even change it to false. Could you add some code of where you think it has gone wrong?

Comment: hello...Thanks for your reply..
Actually this problem is occurring only on the production.
this problem is not coming in the localhost.
that's why I am not able to show you the code for where it is going wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wont be able to help without viewing and understanding the code, sorry.